# Using a XML DataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I was using a `SqlDataReader` to read data from a `Scenarios` table as such:

```
string Data = reader["ScenarioData"].ToString();
```

However, now my `ScenarioData` field is XML `ntext`. How can I read the XML data with the `DataReader`?  For example, lets say I wanted to read the Url "http://google.com".

Scenario Data field:

```
<Scenario Name="Scenario1" Feature="Feature1">
<Steps>
<Step Url="http://google.com"></Step>
</Steps>
</Scenario>
```

Comment: I suggest you read the [MSDN Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ta6tz4.aspx) on this.

Comment: What is the data type of the column? XML or NTEXT?

Answer (score 4):

Given the fact that you have already your XML in a variable of type string, I would suggest the following :

```
SqlDataReader reader= cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    ..... 
    // you have already an xml string stocked in data
    string data = (string)reader["ScenarioData"];
    // parse it
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(data);
    var step = doc.Descendants("Step").Attributes().FirstOrDefault();
    var url = step != null ? step.Value : String.Empty;
    ......
}
```

There is also a way to read Xml using SqlXml, you can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh9a9y6s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks for pointing this out. ToString() originally was in the question, I didn't paid attention. I modified it and added additional information.

Comment: @JohnSaunders That's why at the bottom of my post, there is a link. Anyway, doesn't matter...

Comment: Since it's an ntext and not an XML column, you are just parsing it as XML using the GetSqlXml command.  What does it matter when you change the string into XML?  I see this answer as perfectly reasonable and no different from the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

var xml = XElement.Parse(reader["ScenarioData"].ToString());

//assuming there can be multiple <step> elements
var steps = xml.Element("Scenario").Element("Steps").Elements("Step");
var url = steps.First().Attribute("Url").Value;
```

Comment: @JohnSaunders - how is that already XML? the OP states that the column datatype is NTEXT, not xml, so it is a string.

Comment: I misread the question. I've deleted my answer. I would like to upvote your answer, but I can't do that until you make some edit to the answer.